# Cluster Validation : how to validate and measure predefined clusters

Tags: python, validation, cluster-analysis

I am new to python and working on a consumer dataset where we have used LCA, K-Means, DBSCAN and Spectral Clustering to compute the clusters. In all these methods, number of clusters are different (eg-5 clusters in K-Means but 7 in LCA) and Independent variables may or may not be same (eg- 12 independent variables in K-means but 10 in LCA). Now I want to validate the clusters using Cluster Cohesion, Cluster separation, Entropy, Purity, Jaccard Coeff, RAND index etc. I need help on;

1. Are these measures are appropriate regarding cluster validation?
2. Is there any function/library in python where I can calculate all these at once?
3. How to calculate these in python if there is no function/library available.

Hope I am clear and Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I am trying with adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred) but having an error ValueError: labels_true must be 1D: shape is (2000, 1). The no. of records in my dataset are 2000. where X1,X2 ... are different independent variables, 

Cluster_Sol5 = [0,3,2,2,3,1,5 .......]
Cluster_Sol7 = [0,7,1,1,1,1,5,6.....]

Answer (score 0):

[Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation) has all these parameters readily available. Whether they are appropriate? These are the standard and accepted metrics to score clustering results. If clustering was the right tool for your question, these metrics are appropriate to validate your results.